# How to realize a polynomial regression in Pytorch / Python

Tags: python, regression, pytorch, polynomial-approximations

I want my neural network to solve a polynomial regression problem like y=(x*x) + 2x -3.

So right now I created a network with 1 input node, 100 hidden nodes and 1 output node and gave it a lot of epochs to train with a high test data size. The problem is that the prediction after like 20000 epochs is okayish, but much worse then the linear regression predictions after training.

```
import torch
from torch import Tensor
from torch.nn import Linear, MSELoss, functional as F
from torch.optim import SGD, Adam, RMSprop
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np


# define our data generation function
def data_generator(data_size=1000):
    # f(x) = y = x^2 + 4x - 3
    inputs = []
    labels = []

    # loop data_size times to generate the data
    for ix in range(data_size):
        # generate a random number between 0 and 1000
        x = np.random.randint(1000) / 1000

        # calculate the y value using the function x^2 + 4x - 3
        y = (x * x) + (4 * x) - 3

        # append the values to our input and labels lists
        inputs.append([x])
        labels.append([y])

    return inputs, labels


# define the model
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = Linear(1, 100)
        self.fc2 = Linear(100, 1)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x


model = Net()
# define the loss function
critereon = MSELoss()
# define the optimizer
optimizer = SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

# define the number of epochs and the data set size
nb_epochs = 20000
data_size = 1000

# create our training loop
for epoch in range(nb_epochs):
    X, y = data_generator(data_size)
    X = Variable(Tensor(X))
    y = Variable(Tensor(y))


    epoch_loss = 0;


    y_pred = model(X)

    loss = critereon(y_pred, y)

    epoch_loss = loss.data
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    loss.backward()

    optimizer.step()

    print("Epoch: {} Loss: {}".format(epoch, epoch_loss))

# test the model
model.eval()
test_data = data_generator(1)
prediction = model(Variable(Tensor(test_data[0][0])))
print("Prediction: {}".format(prediction.data[0]))
print("Expected: {}".format(test_data[1][0]))
```

Is their a way to get way better results? I wondered if I should try to get 3 outputs, call them a, b and c, such that y= a(x*x)+b(x)+c. But I have no idea how to implement that and train my neural network.

Comment: input is just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this problem, it might be such easier if you consider the `Net()` with 1 `Linear` layer as `Linear Regression` with inputs features including `[x^2, x]`.

### Generate your data

```py
import torch
from torch import Tensor
from torch.nn import Linear, MSELoss, functional as F
from torch.optim import SGD, Adam, RMSprop
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np

# define our data generation function
def data_generator(data_size=1000):
    # f(x) = y = x^2 + 4x - 3
    inputs = []
    labels = []

    # loop data_size times to generate the data
    for ix in range(data_size):
        # generate a random number between 0 and 1000
        x = np.random.randint(2000) / 1000 # I edited here for you

        # calculate the y value using the function x^2 + 4x - 3
        y = (x * x) + (4 * x) - 3

        # append the values to our input and labels lists
        inputs.append([x*x, x])
        labels.append([y])

    return inputs, labels
```

#### Define your model

```py
# define the model
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = Linear(2, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc1(x)

model = Net()
```

### Then train it we get:

```
Epoch: 0 Loss: 33.75775909423828
Epoch: 1000 Loss: 0.00046704441774636507
Epoch: 2000 Loss: 9.437128483114066e-07
Epoch: 3000 Loss: 2.0870876138445738e-09
Epoch: 4000 Loss: 1.126847400112485e-11
Prediction: 5.355223655700684
Expected: [5.355224999999999]
```

### The coeffients

The coefficients `a`, `b`, `c` you are looking for are actually the weight and bias of the `self.fc1`:

```py
print('a & b:', model.fc1.weight)
print('c:', model.fc1.bias)

# Output
a & b: Parameter containing:
tensor([[1.0000, 4.0000]], requires_grad=True)
c: Parameter containing:
tensor([-3.0000], requires_grad=True)
```

In only 5000 epochs, all converges: `a` -> 1, `b` -> 4, and `c` -> -3.

The model is such a light-weight with only 3 parameters instead of:

```
(100 + 1) + (100 + 1) = 202 parameters in the old model
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much that is way easier! I never thought about that.

Comment: Oh sorry, i didnt knew that. That was my first question :D

Comment: I realized that if `x` in `0-2.0` it convert faster in 5000 epochs, because you set `x` in range `0-1.0` if would really hard to see the contribution of `x^2`. Imagine `0.1^2`  10 times smaller than `0.1`. I just edited the result.

Comment: Thank you again. i just recognize, taht when you put the number generator outside of the training loop, so you only call it ones, its way faster and gets better results as well.